# Sort Array in the bases of another array

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, nsarray, nssortdescriptor

I have 1 array of object which contains employees data. its unsorted.
I have another array which contains object which have employee data and order for that.

For example:

```
Employee *emp;
Ordered *orderedEmp = [[Ordered alloc]init];
ordreredEmp.emp = emp;
orderedEmp.order = any number;


NSArray *arr1 = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@emp,emp,nil];
NSArray *arr2 = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@orderedEmp,orderedEmp,nil];
```

Now here i want to sort first array according to second array.

Thanks In advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better you can use `NSPredicate`  & `NSSortDescriptor`

```
   NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"emp == %@" ,@"emp"];
    [NSMutablearray filterUsingPredicate:predicate];


 NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Title" ascending:TRUE];
        [NSMutablearray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
        [sortDescriptor release];
```